# Fixing malformed HTML in PHP?

Tags: php, html, parsing

I am constructing a large HTML document from fragments supplied by users that have the annoying habit of being malformed in various ways.  Browsers are robust and forgiving enough but I want to be able to validate and (ideally) fix any malformed HTML if at all possible.  For example:

```
<td><b>Title</td>
```

can be reasonably fixed to:

```
<td><b>Title</b></td>
```

Is there a way of doing this easily in PHP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [HTML Tidy](http://devzone.zend.com/article/761-Tidying-up-your-HTML-with-PHP-5), man pages are [here](http://au.php.net/tidy).

Comment: However there are still few problems with it. It used to remove my intended white spaces, causing some JS problems. Also it parses <script> tags in a way that IE6 doesn't recognize them sometimes - if you still want to optimize your webby for IE6.

Comment: Tidy should not be used on untrusted input: http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison#Tidy

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). From their site:

> HTML Purifier is a standards-compliant
>   HTML filter library written in PHP.
>   HTML Purifier will not only remove all
>   malicious code (better known as XSS)
>   with a thoroughly audited, secure yet
>   permissive whitelist, it will also
>   make sure your documents are standards
>   compliant, something only achievable
>   with a comprehensive knowledge of
>   W3C's specifications. Tired of using
>   BBCode due to the current landscape of
>   deficient or insecure HTML filters?
>   Have a WYSIWYG editor but never been
>   able to use it? Looking for
>   high-quality, standards-compliant,
>   open-source components for that
>   application you're building? HTML
>   Purifier is for you!

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use Tidy (sometimes hosting service do not activate this php module), you can use this PHP class: http://www.barattalo.it/html-fixer/

Comment: Note that the project is no longer maintained. Its last update was on 06/07/2010. But it's easy to use and has one single file compared to HTML Purifier.