# How to valid the many possible HTML pages which my PHP code may generate?

Tags: php, parsing, validation

Every path through the PHP code might generate a different HTML page.

I generally take a few variants of each success case and run them through the W3C HTML validator every release ... and at best I can hope to cover 20% of the pages which my code might generate.

This sounds like a tall order, but is there any tool which can at least reduce the amount of invalid HTML which my code might produce?  Even just catching my favourite `<p.` instead of `<p>` would be a boon.

I can see how tough it would be ... even catching missing end tags might mean parsing through `if ... else` or `switch` logic in PHP ...

I think I just answered my own question ... but ...

Comment: Indeed, since PHP is Turing-complete, the program that you want could be used to solve the halting problem, and therefore cannot exist in general. As for catching easy cases in practice, I don't know.

Comment: For easy cases....hate to say this, but open your editor and look through the code. It's rough, but it's pretty much all you'll be able to do. (Please - if someone can disqualify this statement, please do, because manually checking code _sucks_.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [X/Html Validator in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030392/x-html-validator-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at PHP's [Tidy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.cleanrepair.php)